# Posbox - scan decode incorrect

Tags: python, odoo, barcode-scanner

I can't scan correctly a barcode when my scanner is plugged to Posbox.
For example, when I scan the barcode (EAN13) 3288190200005, I've got "#@**!()@))))%"

The log of posbox is :

```
DEBUG ? openerp.addons.hw_scanner.controllers.main: pushing barcode #@**!()@))))% from device /dev/input/by-id/usb-Honeywell_Scanning_and_Mobility_Honeywell_Scanning_and_Mobility_Scanner-event-kbd, name "Honeywell Scanning and Mobility Honeywell Scanning and Mobility Scanner", phys "usb-3f980000.usb-1.3/input0
```

But when I plugged my scanner directly to my computer, it works without problem.
IP posbox is correctly set; I have a popup error : "Barcode unknown".
I have already reinstall posbox version 15 or version 16, nothing change.

What should I do ?

Comment: If I'm reading that message correctly, the scanner has a USB interface that emulates a keyboard, so incorrect scanning should be impossible unless the scanner is misconfigured. Can you scan into a text editor?

Comment: This related with keyboard,

Comment: It's realy claer that `'#'` is `3`, and `0000` is `))))` and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, it was the keyboard country of the scanner. It was configured to French, and Posbox needs US Keyboard.
I scan the barcode for US keyboard, and it works.